# Eclipse executable file doesnt exist

Tags: eclipse, executable

I have a proble with eclipse.
I have download Eclipse and extract it and there was no problem then for some reasons i had to delete (shift+delete) it and now when I extract it again , there is no executable file for launch the eclipse !
what should I do ???

Comment: Eclipse disappeared when you shift-deleted it

Comment: so how can I run Eclipse ???

Comment: If you corrupted your downloaded ZIP ... maybe download again?

Comment: i dont deletet the zip file ... i extract it and delete the extracted file :)

Comment: Download and reinstall